# How to filter data and display it on Detailed Mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a detailed mat-table where I want to display data.
For now, I am able to display data in both the main table and the detailed table.
But what I want is that the main table row should only contain 1 row for a specific date and inside that row, it should contain other rows of the same date.
Suppose I have 9 days data,3 records for each day, say 01/Feb,02/Feb, and 03/Feb so I would like to display only 3 rows in the main table and when a user clicks on row 01/Feb he should see 3 rows inside the detailed table.
Similarly, if he clicks on 02/Feb he should see the data corresponding to only 02/Feb.

Right now my table shows all the 9 records(rows) in the main table and if I click on a row from the main table it again shows 9 records. 
How can I filter the data to display according to my need?

Code for HTML :-

```
<table
        mat-table
        [dataSource]="jobExecutionList"
        multiTemplateDataRows
        class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container
            matColumnDef="{{ column }}"
            *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                {{ element[column] }}
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one 
        column that spans across all columns -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="1">
                <div
                    class="example-element-detail"
                    [@detailExpand]="
                        element == expandedElement
                            ? 'expanded'
                            : 'collapsed'">
                  <table mat-table [dataSource]="jobExecutionList">
                        <!-- Position Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element2">
                                {{ element2.id }}
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <!-- Name Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="executionDate">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                Execution Date
                            </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element2">
                                {{
                                    element2.executionDate}}
                                        <!-- | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' -->

                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <!-- Name Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="lable">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                Label
                            </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element2">
                                {{ element2.lable }}
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- Weight Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="previousTimePeriod">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                Previous Time Period
                            </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element2">
                                {{ element2.previousTimePeriod }}
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- Symbol Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="afterTimePeriod">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                After Time Period
                            </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element2">
                                {{ element2.afterTimePeriod }}
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- Symbol Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                Status
                            </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element2">
                                {{ element2.status }}
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <tr
                            mat-header-row
                            *matHeaderRowDef="
                                columnsToDisplay2;
                                sticky: true
                            "
                        ></tr>
                        <tr
                            mat-row
                            *matRowDef="
                                let row2;
                                columns: columnsToDisplay2
                            "
                        ></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr
            mat-header-row
            *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky: true"
        ></tr>
        <tr
            mat-row
            *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay"
            class="example-element-row"
            [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
            (click)="
                expandedElement =
                    expandedElement === element ? null : element
            "
        ></tr>
        <!-- Group header -->

        <tr
            mat-row
            *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']"
            class="example-detail-row"
        ></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Code for Typescript:-

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.rendertable();
}
rendertable() {
    const project = JSON.parse(this.dataService.getObject('project'));
    this.recommendationService
        .getJobList(project.id)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.jobExecutionList = new MatTableDataSource();
            this.jobExecutionList.data = data;
            this.jobExecutionList.sort = this.sort;
            this.jobExecutionList.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
}
export interface Element {
id: number;
lable: string,
executionDate: string;
previousTimePeriod: string;
afterTimePeriod: string;
status: string;
jobId: string;
executionId: string;
}
```

Alternative solution can be to group the data based on date can someone show me how to do it. I am fairly new to angular and programming